# According to the context, which is grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

According to the context, which is correct, #1 or #2?

> 1. Donald Trump was elected President. He is the 45th President of the United States.
> 2. Donald Trump was an elected President. He is the 45th President of the United States.

Answer (score 2):

The first is fine. It uses the form of the verb elect that has two objects:

> We elected him president.

In a passive structure

> He was elected president.

The second uses the adjective "elected" to describe a president

> Trump is an elected president. Kim is an unelected president.

If you use *was* it strongly implies he is no longer President

> Abraham Lincoln was an elected president.